# Chrome does not open intent when clicking deeplink in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, deep-linking

I have the following scenario. I write a notice in the android notice app, which contains the url domain.com/id/data. When i click it, i want to open it with chrome.

On the web server the url will be redirected to a php page. In the php code i finally redirect to the intent to open an own app. I did it like described in: [google chrome intents](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents).

When i open the link in the chrome directly: domain.com/id/data. The App will be opened properly. But when i open the link in the notice app in android and select chrome i got an error message that the site cannot be opened. The url, which cannot be opened it: intent://operation/#Intent;scheme=ownapp;package=com.ownapp;end

When i try the same with firefox in android it works. Only chrome seems to have problems now. I use Chrome 49 on Android 6.0.1.

Someone has any idea?

Comment: I figured out that it is  a problem with the OS running the web server. On Ubuntu it works but the problem only is there if using raspbian (Debian) and php

Comment: I have the exact same problem. My web server is running CentOS. It will be a big problem to install a new OS on my server so I'm wondering if there's some patch or fix I can apply to make it work.